# How to view the image in circle wise

Tags: android

I view the image in Vshape wise how to view the circle wise.

```
public void vShape(LinearLayout lv, ArrayList<MyLinearLayout> st) {
        LinearLayout table = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        table.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
       LinearLayout row=null;
        for (int i = 0; i < st.size(); i++) {
            if((i%NO_OF_ROWS==0)&&(i+3<=st.size())){

             row = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
             row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
             row.addView(st.get(i).getLv());

                LinearLayout row1 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                row1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


                ImageView im1 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                im1.setMinimumHeight(50);
                im1.setMinimumWidth(50);
                row1.addView(im1);
                row1.addView(st.get(i+1).getLv());
                row.addView(row1);


                row.addView(st.get(i+2).getLv());

                table.addView(row);
            }

        }

        lv.addView(table);      

    }
```

http://pasteboard.co/qeavamO.png

I view the image in this shape wise

```
1     3
   2
```

but i want circle wise like

```
   4
1     3
   2
```

how to change the code please help.

Answer (score 0):

use CircleLayout  Find the view here

https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout